# redux:props.color is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have set a function as `action` called `coler` and bind it to my component but it cannot identify it with the error:

```
props.color is not a function
```

The action function is:

```
export default function collorSetter(color){
  return {type:'Color',payload:color};

}
```

The component is:

```
    import React,{Component} from 'react';

    export default class Letter extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if(props.activeWord!=props.wordId)
        props.color({ color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal' });
    if(props.letterId>props.activeLetter && props.activeWord==props.wordId)
        props.color({ color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal' });
    if(props.letterId<=props.activeLetter && props.activeWord==props.wordId  && props.value==props.newTypedLetter)
        props.color({ color:'green', fontWeight: 'bold' });
    if(props.letterId<=props.activeLetter && props.activeWord==props.wordId && props.value!=props.newTypedLetter)
        props.color({ color:'red',fontWeight: 'bold' });
  }


      render(){

          return(<div style={this.props.letterColor}>
                      {this.props.value}
                </div>);
      }

    }
```

and then in the container i have connected the component and the action:

```
import Letter from '../components/Letter';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import { ColorSetter } from '../actions/ColorSetter';

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {newTypedLetter:state.newTypedLetter, letterColor:state.letterColor}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({color:ColorSetter},dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Letter);
```

Why it cannot recognize my action in the **props**?

**Update:**

The purpose of this component is to set a certain style on a letters based on some conditions (conditions in the constructor). When the component get loaded the constructor should be called and set a style.

Here is the reducer part:

```
export default function(state=null,action){
    switch(action.type){
      case 'Color':
          return action.payload;
      default:
          return { color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal'}
    }


}
```

I expect that, when i call the `props.color(color)` it sends the color to the reducer and the reducer will set it as `letterColor` then in using line style=`{this.props.letterColor}` in the component, i can change the style.

Comment: Why do you `return` from a constructor? Next - there is no named export `ColorSetter` in the `ColorSetter` module. Next - you should put all your logic in `render` not a constructor.

Comment: `props.color({ color:'black', fontWeight: 'normal' });` --- now this statement makes no sense.

Comment: 1. Because it does nothing. If you remove it nothing changes

Comment: What "does not work"? You have not explained what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, I have already explained it in my first comment: there is no named export `ColorSetter` in the `ColorSetter` module.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all I think the function is called `colorSetter` instead of `collorSetter`.

And your component doesn't recognize the prop simply because you are importing it wrong.
I mean you export your action with the name `colorSetter` but you are importing it with`{ColorSetter}` *(With capital C)*, and you have to use exaclty the same name as it was exported, it means `{colorSetter}`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic structure that you can expand on...

In your action:

```
export default function setColor(color) {
    return { type: 'COLOR', payload: color };
};
```

In your reducer:

```
export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch action.type {
        case 'COLOR':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { color: payload.action });
    }
}
```

In your container:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return { letterColor: state.color }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { setColor: bindActionCreator(setColor, dispatch) };
}
```

In your component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.activeWord) {
        this.props.setColor('blue');
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ color: this.props.letterColor }}>text</div>
    );
}
```